# Taxonomy archive showing no results

Tags: custom-taxonomy, taxonomy, terms, archives, tax-query

I have the file `taxonomy-project.php` and am trying to view results for some of my terms.

I keep getting a result of `NO` even though I have a post applied to that particular term.

## taxonomy-project.php

```
<?php get_header(); ?>

    <section>
        <div class="container">
            <div class="row">
                <div class="col-12">

                    <?php if(have_posts()) : ?>
                        <div class="fancybox">
                            <div class="row">
                                <?php while(have_posts()) : the_post(); ?>
                                    YES
                                <?php endwhile; ?>
                            </div>
                        </div>

                    <?php else : ?>
                        NO
                    <?php endif; ?>

                </div>
            </div>


        </div>
    </section>


<?php get_footer (); ?>
```

## Functions.php

```
    // register custom posts
add_action( 'init', 'create_post_type' );
function create_post_type() {
    register_post_type( 'work',
        array(
            'labels' => array(
            'name' => __( 'Work' ),
            'singular_name' => __( 'Work' ),
            'add_new_item' => __( 'Add New Work' ),
            'edit_item' => __( 'Edit Work' ),
            'new_item' => __( 'New Work' ),
            'view_item' => __( 'View Work' ),
            'search_items' => __( 'Search Work' )
            ),
            'public' => true,
            'exclude_from_search' => true,
            'menu_position' => 5,
            'supports' => array('title', 'thumbnail'),
            'taxonomies' => array('project')
        )
    );
}


// register custom taxonomies
 function taxonomyRegister_init() {
   // create a new taxonomy
   register_taxonomy(
     'project',
     'work',
     array(
       'label' => __('Project'),
       'sort' => true,
       'args' => array('orderby' => 'term_order'),
       'hierarchical' => true
     )
   );
 }
add_action( 'init', 'taxonomyRegister_init' );
```

## Query

```
    WP_Query Object
    (
        [query] => Array
            (
                [project] => lorem-ipsum
            )
    
        [query_vars] => Array
            (
                [project] => lorem-ipsum
                [error] => 
                [m] => 
                [p] => 0
                [post_parent] => 
                [subpost] => 
                [subpost_id] => 
                [attachment] => 
                [attachment_id] => 0
                [name] => 
                [pagename] => 
                [page_id] => 0
                [second] => 
                [minute] => 
                [hour] => 
                [day] => 0
                [monthnum] => 0
                [year] => 0
                [w] => 0
                [category_name] => 
                [tag] => 
                [cat] => 
                [tag_id] => 
                [author] => 
                [author_name] => 
                [feed] => 
                [tb] => 
                [paged] => 0
                [meta_key] => 
                [meta_value] => 
                [preview] => 
                [s] => 
                [sentence] => 
                [title] => 
                [fields] => 
                [menu_order] => 
                [embed] => 
                [category__in] => Array
                    (
                    )
    
                [category__not_in] => Array
                    (
                    )
    
                [category__and] => Array
                    (
                    )
    
                [post__in] => Array
                    (
                    )
    
                [post__not_in] => Array
                    (
                    )
    
                [post_name__in] => Array
                    (
                    )
    
                [tag__in] => Array
                    (
                    )
    
                [tag__not_in] => Array
                    (
                    )
    
                [tag__and] => Array
                    (
                    )
    
                [tag_slug__in] => Array
                    (
                    )
    
                [tag_slug__and] => Array
                    (
                    )
    
                [post_parent__in] => Array
                    (
                    )
    
                [post_parent__not_in] => Array
                    (
                    )
    
                [author__in] => Array
                    (
                    )
    
                [author__not_in] => Array
                    (
                    )
    
                [ignore_sticky_posts] => 
                [suppress_filters] => 
                [cache_results] => 1
                [update_post_term_cache] => 1
                [lazy_load_term_meta] => 1
                [update_post_meta_cache] => 1
                [post_type] => 
                [posts_per_page] => 10
                [nopaging] => 
                [comments_per_page] => 50
                [no_found_rows] => 
                [taxonomy] => project
                [term] => lorem-ipsum
                [order] => DESC
            )
    
        [tax_query] => WP_Tax_Query Object
            (
                [queries] => Array
                    (
                        [0] => Array
                            (
                                [taxonomy] => project
                                [terms] => Array
                                    (
                                        [0] => lorem-ipsum
                                    )
    
                                [field] => slug
                                [operator] => IN
                                [include_children] => 1
                            )
    
                    )
    
                [relation] => AND
                [table_aliases:protected] => Array
                    (
                        [0] => wp_term_relationships
                    )
    
                [queried_terms] => Array
                    (
                        [project] => Array
                            (
                                [terms] => Array
                                    (
                                        [0] => lorem-ipsum
                                    )
    
                                [field] => slug
                            )
    
                    )
    
                [primary_table] => wp_posts
                [primary_id_column] => ID
            )
    
        [meta_query] => WP_Meta_Query Object
            (
                [queries] => Array
                    (
                    )
    
                [relation] => 
                [meta_table] => 
                [meta_id_column] => 
                [primary_table] => 
                [primary_id_column] => 
                [table_aliases:protected] => Array
                    (
                    )
    
                [clauses:protected] => Array
                    (
                    )
    
                [has_or_relation:protected] => 
            )
    
        [date_query] => 
        [queried_object] => WP_Term Object
            (
                [term_id] => 2
                [name] => Lorem ipsum
                [slug] => lorem-ipsum
                [term_group] => 0
                [term_taxonomy_id] => 2
                [taxonomy] => project
                [description] => 
                [parent] => 0
                [count] => 1
                [filter] => raw
            )
    
        [queried_object_id] => 2
        [request] => SELECT SQL_CALC_FOUND_ROWS  wp_posts.ID FROM wp_posts  LEFT JOIN wp_term_relationships ON (wp_posts.ID = wp_term_relationships.object_id) WHERE 1=1  AND ( 
      wp_term_relationships.term_taxonomy_id IN (2)
    ) AND wp_posts.post_type IN ('post', 'page', 'attachment') AND (wp_posts.post_status = 'publish' OR wp_posts.post_status = 'acf-disabled') GROUP BY wp_posts.ID ORDER BY wp_posts.menu_order, wp_posts.post_date DESC LIMIT 0, 10
        [posts] => Array
            (
            )
    
        [post_count] => 0
        [current_post] => -1
        [in_the_loop] => 
        [comment_count] => 0
        [current_comment] => -1
        [found_posts] => 0
        [max_num_pages] => 0
        [max_num_comment_pages] => 0
        [is_single] => 
        [is_preview] => 
        [is_page] => 
        [is_archive] => 1
        [is_date] => 
        [is_year] => 
        [is_month] => 
        [is_day] => 
        [is_time] => 
        [is_author] => 
        [is_category] => 
        [is_tag] => 
        [is_tax] => 1
        [is_search] => 
        [is_feed] => 
        [is_comment_feed] => 
        [is_trackback] => 
        [is_home] => 
        [is_privacy_policy] => 
        [is_404] => 
        [is_embed] => 
        [is_paged] => 
        [is_admin] => 
        [is_attachment] => 
        [is_singular] => 
        [is_robots] => 
        [is_favicon] => 
        [is_posts_page] => 
        [is_post_type_archive] => 
        [query_vars_hash:WP_Query:private] => c087b9cf5d8d955411d9eb52431cd969
        [query_vars_changed:WP_Query:private] => 
        [thumbnails_cached] => 
        [stopwords:WP_Query:private] => 
        [compat_fields:WP_Query:private] => Array
            (
                [0] => query_vars_hash
                [1] => query_vars_changed
            )
    
        [compat_methods:WP_Query:private] => Array
            (
                [0] => init_query_flags
                [1] => parse_tax_query
            )
)
```

Comment: What's your global `$wp_query` show? Have you resaved permalinks?

Comment: @Howdy_McGee yep I've tried resaving my permalinks but no luck — I've just updated my question now with my wp_query

Comment: If you manually set the post type in `pre_get_posts` ( checking if it's `is_tax( 'project' )` does it then appear?

Comment: @Howdy_McGee Im struggling to get my head around `pre_get_posts` sorry!

Comment: @Howdy_McGee I've found the problem! have just posted an answer

Answer (score 1):

I've found the problem, and now I realise I had this exact same problem years ago on a different project:

This:

```
'exclude_from_search' => true
```

Needed changing to:

```
'exclude_from_search' => false
'has_archive' => true,
```

I don't get why excluding a post type from search should affect archive templates, but at least it's fixed now.